# how to change an image source more than once using onclick on html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to have an image, once clicked move on to image 2, then once image 2 is clicked it moves on to image 3, then image 4 and so on, but I am struggling to find a way to have more than 2 images? So far I have tried various different ways such as repeating the code I already have, using multiple if statements and switch statement but I just cannot seem to be able to use more than 2 images. I am only a beginner coder so it is difficult to see where I am going wrong. the expected outcome would be just to have a number of images appearing after each one is clicked.

So far the code that I have that's working is:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>



  <head>



    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

  <title>Social Media</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">



    var mysrc = "image1.jpg";

        function changeImage() {

            if (mysrc == "image1.jpg") {

                document.images["pic"].src = "image1.jpg";

                document.images["pic"].alt = "image1";

                mysrc = "image.jpg";

                }



            else {

                document.images["pic"].src = "image.jpg";

                document.images["pic"].alt = "image";

                mysrc = "image1.jpg";

            }         



        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <img src="image.jpg"

        alt="image" id="pic" class="portrait"

        onclick="changeImage()"

        width="1000px" height="500px"

        style="cursor:pointer">







</body>

</html>
```

and i have been able to get the same results by doing:

```
function change() {
var image = document.getElementById('image');
image.src = "image1.jpg"
}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<img src="image.jpg" alt="text" id="image" onclick="change();">
```

but i just cant seem to get more than 2 images? as mentioned I am just a beginner so I'm really not sure if it's just me making stupid mistakes, any advice would be really helpful

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but the code only mentions two image filenames, `image.jpg` and `image1.jpg`. Where do you think a third or fourth image should come from?

Comment: Sorry, probably didn't explain very well but so far that code that I have included is the code that I have that is working, whenever I try to add a third and forth image it breaks and I can't get it to work anymore so I'm looking for a method that will include the next couple of images, if that makes any sense? Apologies if I'm not explaining this well I don't really know the correct terminology to use

Comment: Then you should show the code where you attempt to add a third image so that someone will be able to tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: I quickly made a working script for you here [https://jsfiddle.net/9o4p6qcw/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/9o4p6qcw/1/). Didn't turn it into an answer because it's general code and not an adeptation on your code. But it should get you going :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll give that a go now!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be to do this using an array and a simple variable counter.

```
var imgCount = 0;
var images = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png"...];
```

`imgCount` will get added to every time `<img>` is clicked.

```
<script>
var imgCount = -1;
var images = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png"...];
function change() {
  imgCount++;
  var image = document.getElementById('image');
  image.src = images[imgCount];
}
</script>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="text" id="image" onclick="change()">
```

The `src` is now called from the array. `imgCount` serves as the counter of the amount of times the image has been clicked and is used to find the correct src with the array since it also serves as an index.

If you don't know much about arrays read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

I'm sure that you don't have an endless amount of pictures, so you can also use this:

```
<script>
var imgCount = -1;
var images = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png"];
function change() {
  if (imgCount !== images.length - 1)
    imgCount++;
  else 
    imgCount = 0;
  var image = document.getElementById('image');
  image.src = images[imgCount];
}
</script>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="text" id="image" onclick="change()">
```

Now, if `<img>` is clicked and it is on the last image, it will go back to the beginning. The if statement sees whether or not the counter equals the amount of images in the array. If it hasn't it keeps adding. If it hasn't, it sets the counter back to 0.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for!